# Object Oriented Modelling Advice

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oop, module, composition

hoping for a bit of guidance with modelling decisions for an RoR app I’m planning to build. It’ll be a rental platform hosting with multiple rental vendors. I'm supposing the following classes and or modules and my question is about modelling, composition and inheritance. I suppose the following classes and or modules:

- Products (a module? Included in ProductLibrary, VendorCatalogue and Orders)
- Product Library (every possible rental item, has_many Product objects, 1..n with Products)
- Vendors (1..1 with vendor catalogue, 1..n with Orders)
- Vendor Catalogue (has_many Products from the 'Product Library object' and individual to each ‘Vendor’, 1..1 with Vendors)
- Customers (1..n orders)
- Orders (comprised of Products from the vendor catalogue, 1..1 with customer, 1..n with products and n..1 with Vendors)
- Maybe there should be an Account class with common account attributes and methods which both Vendors and Customers inherit from?

Excuse any lack of clarity with the way I’ve laid out the above, I’m failry new to OO and programming in general. Could I have any thoughts and advice on my below thoughts re. the best modelling of the above objects:

- My thoughts are that Products should be a module(?), as other classes 'have products', as opposed to 'are products’?
- I’m unsure that I even need a Product library (would it just be products.all?)?
- As there are multiple Vendors, each of whom with differing product ranges/catalogues, I do need a VendorCatalogue object to  contain each vendors unique collection of Product objects. Is this the best way to do this?
- Ought Vendors and Customers to inherit from a parent Account class to keep DRY?
- Would the most sensible place to start be with building the Products class/module, ProductsLibrary (if rqd), then Vendors, then VendorCatalogue, then Customers, then Orders?

Any help on the above appreciated, thankyou.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My thoughts are that Products should be a module(?), as other classes
>   'have products', as opposed to 'are products’?

I'd prefer to make Product an AR::Model. In fact it is a separate entity with its own behavior and state. It is a core model of your app, if I understood everything right.

> I’m unsure that I even need a Product library (would it just be
>   products.all?)?

If you will have some complex product search logic, then you should make something like ProductRepository. Check out Repository pattern here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649690.aspx.

> As there are multiple Vendors, each of whom with differing product
>   ranges/catalogues, I do need a VendorCatalogue object to contain each
>   vendors unique collection of Product objects. Is this the best way to
>   do this?

Definitely you should make this object.

> Ought Vendors and Customers to inherit from a parent Account class to
>   keep DRY?

It depends of your logic. If both customers and vendors have some accounts, with transactions, withdrawals and so on, then you can include to both Account module.
But be careful. You should think a bit. If they have different logic, then each of them should have CustomerAccount or VendorAccount.

> Would the most sensible place to start be with building the Products
>   class/module, ProductsLibrary (if rqd), then Vendors, then
>   VendorCatalogue, then Customers, then Orders?

I thing this order is good enough.

Comment: Thanks Stanislav, pondering, researching and learning more about the points in your answer now. E.g. Have not heard of Repository Patterns until today ;) thank you for the guidance.

Comment: If I helped you, it would be great, if you mark my answer as correct :)

Comment: BTW, AR::Model is a simple rails active record model, nothing complex

Comment: Thanks Stanislav. When you say that you'd like to make Products an AR::Model, of course all of these Objects would be AR::Models wouldn't they, is they all need to be tables in the DB; Products, ProductCatalogues, Vendors, Customers, Orders? The only object that I mention that I see would not be an AR::Model would be the Account class. So if what i say is correct I'm just wondering why you specifically said that the Products object would be an AR::Model without suggesting the same for all of the other objects, bar Account?

Comment: Because of this line: "Products (a module? Included in ProductLibrary, VendorCatalogue and Orders)"
I meant that it should not be a ruby module. It has to be a class, inherited from AR::Base